WPEngine web header rules breaking my wp-login
So I manage a wordpress page for a business, it is hosted in WPENGINE where they offer in their dashboard an option to configure the web header security (X-frame-options, set-cookies, Subresource integrity), I received an alert that some of these are not secure and I should work on them, I when to the wpengine tool to do so, but some of them break the site or parts of the site when using them (most of them break the wp-login, so no one is able to access the wp-dashboard). The ones that I still need to manage and are causing issues are:

Cookies (set-cookies)
Content Security Policy (CSP)
Subresource Integrity (SRI)

Images:
Mozilla Scan
WPEngine web header security dashboard
I have tried following the rules set in the Mozilla scan, and looking around, but this dashboard does not seem to be a common practice so I can not find a lot of examples or documentation about, hopefully someone else who uses WPEngine will be around here.
